# how can i get the value of hidden field in grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net

the order number of hidden field in grid view is 7.

when i click the button the line

```
string sValue = ((HiddenField)GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;
```

gives error which is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
          <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate> 

                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" 
                    Value='<%#Eval("RSS_ID")%>'/>

            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
```

c# side

```
else if (e.CommandName == "View")
{
    string sValue = ((HiddenField)GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;                   
}
```

Comment: can you post your full event code...as well as your grid markup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

did you try this?

```
HiddenField field = (HiddenField)GridView.Rows[GridView.SelectedIndex].FindControl("HiddenField1");
```

If yes, how about this one?

```
HiddenField field = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;
```

Here is another one you could try,

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{    
     HiddenField field = e.Row.FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;
}
```

Hope this helps...cheers

Comment: @leventkalayz did you try any of the above methods?

Comment: I couldnot do it with this code however, @Dave D's code works. I put it to my project thanks so much

Comment: So many hours wasted looking for such a simple solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Drop the Cells part

If you have the selected row:

```
string sValue = ((HiddenField)GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;
```

If you have e.rowIndex from the command argument:

```
string sValue = ((HiddenField)GridView1.Rows[e.rowIndex].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access SelectedRow, even though I don't see the code, when you actually select the row. My guess is that you're using only some custom command button, that doesn't really set the selected row. Fix that and it should work.

If you can't/don't want to, you would need to write yourself some method to find the row you want and then applying FindControl method to access your hidden field, getting the value...

Or try to post a more complete source code....